# LogParser JSON log files

Tags: json, logparser

Does LogParser support JSON log files?  I am working with an app that outputs simple JSON log files into a folder and I'm trying to run aggregate SQL style queries against the files in the folder.

The format of the files is simple:

```
{"f1":"value", "f2":NumericValue, "f3":"DateValue", etc...}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try out [Musoq](https://github.com/Puchaczov/Musoq) which already has a plugin that lets you treat json as queryable source.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not. LogParser was written when XML was the cool thing :-)
But you can always write your COM extension and LogParser will be able to query JSON files as well.